# Azure SignalR Service is not connected yet, please try again later

Tags: azure, signalr, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-signalr

I am using Azure SignalR on Asp.Net Core 3.1, I receive SignalR message from azure service bus on API side (Back-End) and want to send the message to Angular client side (Front-End) as notification using azure SignalR. But getting this error

Comment: have you found any solution ??

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when using aad connection with a service principal. I forgot to grant `SignalR Service Owner` role to the service principal which caused this error.

After providing the correct role and waiting a bit, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Your server do not connect with SignalR service, please check following:

- the connection string is correct.
- the service mode, if you are using Azure SignalR service SDK, servive mode cannot be `Serverless`
- for free instance, check the resouce usage in Diagnose and solve problems, make sure your message count do not hit the limit.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, getting 503 errors (disguised as CORS errors). The SignalR service was stuck in a 503 state for a half hour.

The fix for me was to create a new Azure SignalR service with a new name, otherwise I could have waited until my original SignalR service came back but I was impatient.

More context here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11353#issuecomment-933959052